# symbol toolbar is partially inactive, teXnicCenter

Tags: editors, texniccenter

I'm using teXniccenter. I want to add math symbols in my documents. I cann't see these symbols graphically. What I have to do to make them active.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You need to have an active document to inserts these elements in. Until such time, *all* constructs will be shaded/unavailable.

To create a new document, the easiest way is to use File > New > File.

[image]

Comment: @ Wener Nothing happend.

Comment: @user31177: They're now active, it seems. You just can't seem to get the additional images/icons to display, right? What version of TeXnicCenter are you running?

Comment: @user31177: My TeXnicCenter version is 2.0 Beta 1 (64 bit). I just [filed a bug/user report](https://sourceforge.net/p/texniccenter/user-reports/1347/) to see whether this is something that could be fixed.